# Store default values from form in state when user doesen't change the default value

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with some fields populated with default values (e.g. a datepicker with "2020-01-01"), they are shown in the form, that works properly. My problem is if the user does not change the field those values won't get put in my state where I need for them to do requests with this form data. Thats obvious because no event is happening. Is there any best practice how to put those values into my state since there is no event happening, when the user doesen't touch those fields?

**Code example:**

```
<Form.Label>Start Date</Form.Label>
<Form.Control className="mb-2" defaultValue="2020-01-01" type="date" />
```

If the user does not change the value of the datepicker, I would want to store this defaultValue into my state, but how could I achieve this without an event happening? Thanks for any help and advice since Im still learning React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState("2020-01-01")
```

and then:

```
<Form.Label>Start Date</Form.Label>
<Form.Control className="mb-2" defaultValue={date} type="date" />
```